# Multithreaded Monte Carlo pi approximation with own pseudorandom number generator - follow up

Tags: c++, random, asynchronous, c++14, numerical-methods

This is a follow up of the question I posted previously [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/150749/multithreaded-monte-carlo-pi-approximation-with-own-pseudorandom-number-generato).

I made some changes, based in the answer by MikeMB, making use of asynchronous calls (with `std::async` and `std::future`), instead of `std::thread` as before.

**monte_carlo_pi.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdint>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include "big_wheel.hpp"

typedef struct
{
    double x, y, z;
} point_t;

static const double PI = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795;
static const std::uint32_t prng_max_value = big_wheel_engine<>::max();

double approximate_pi(std::uint32_t pc,std::uint32_t tp)
{
    return 4.0*(double(pc)/double(tp));
}

double pi_error(double x)
{
    return 100.0*((x-PI)/PI);
}

std::uint32_t generate_points(std::uint32_t nppt)
{
    // PRNGs are initialized and seeded within different threads,
    // instead of using a shared one
    std::random_device rd;
    std::uint32_t seed[16] = {0x0};

    for (int i=0;i<16;i++)
        seed[i] = rd();

    big_wheel_engine<> rgen(
        seed[ 0],seed[ 1],seed[ 2],seed[ 3],
        seed[ 4],seed[ 5],seed[ 6],seed[ 7],
        seed[ 8],seed[ 9],seed[10],seed[11],
        seed[12],seed[13],seed[14],seed[15]
    );

    std::uint32_t pcnt = 0;
    point_t rpt;
    for (std::uint32_t i=0;i<nppt;i++)
    {
        rpt.x = double(rgen())/static_cast<double>(prng_max_value);
        rpt.y = double(rgen())/static_cast<double>(prng_max_value);
        rpt.z = (rpt.x*rpt.x)+(rpt.y*rpt.y);
        if (rpt.z <= 1.0) pcnt++;
    }

    return pcnt;
}

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    // Check number of cores
    std::size_t num_cores = std::thread::hardware_concurrency() ? std::thread::hardware_concurrency() : 1;

    // Future set
    std::vector<std::future<std::uint32_t>> future_set;

    const std::uint32_t num_points = 3221225472;
    const std::uint32_t num_points_per_thread = num_points/num_cores;

    for (std::size_t i=0;i<num_cores;i++)
        future_set.push_back(
            std::async(
                std::launch::async,
                generate_points,
                num_points_per_thread
            )
        );

    // Print info
    std::cout << "Number of points: " << num_points << "\n";
    std::cout << "Number of cores: " << num_cores << "\n";
    std::cout << " ==> Number of points per thread: " << num_points_per_thread << "\n\n";

    std::cout << "Generating random points...\n";

    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point tpa = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    // Number of points inside circle
    std::uint32_t pcnt = 0;

    // Sum points inside circle from all threads
    for (auto &ftr : future_set)
        pcnt += ftr.get();

    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point tpb = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::chrono::duration<double> tm = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(tpb-tpa);

    // Duration
    double dur = tm.count();

    // Approximate pi and calculate error
    const double gen_pi = approximate_pi(pcnt,num_points);
    const double pi_err = pi_error(gen_pi);

    std::cout << "\nResults:\n";
    std::cout << "  Number of points within circle: " << pcnt << "\n";
    std::cout << "  Pi approximation:               " << std::setprecision(32) << gen_pi << "\n";
    std::cout << "  Error:                          " << std::setprecision(10) << pi_err << "%\n";

    std::cout << "Time elapsed: " << std::setprecision(10) << dur << " seconds\n";
}
```

**big_wheel.hpp**:

```
#ifndef BIG_WHEEL_HPP
#define BIG_WHEEL_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdint>
#include <climits>
#include <limits>

template <
    std::uint32_t m = 0x3655accc,
    std::size_t rs1 = 11,std::size_t rs2 = 20,std::size_t rs3 = 14,std::size_t rs4 = 18,
    std::size_t rm1 = 16,std::size_t rm2 = 16,
    std::size_t rf = 7
>
class big_wheel_engine
{
    public:
        typedef std::uint32_t result_type;

        static constexpr std::size_t   state_size = 4096;
        static constexpr std::uint32_t mix_mask  = m;
        static constexpr std::size_t   rot_sel1  = rs1;
        static constexpr std::size_t   rot_sel2  = rs2;
        static constexpr std::size_t   rot_sel3  = rs3;
        static constexpr std::size_t   rot_sel4  = rs4;
        static constexpr std::size_t   rot_mix1  = rm1;
        static constexpr std::size_t   rot_mix2  = rm2;
        static constexpr std::size_t   rot_final = rf;

        big_wheel_engine(
            const result_type& s01 = 0x0,const result_type& s02 = 0x0,const result_type& s03 = 0x0,const result_type& s04 = 0x0,
            const result_type& s05 = 0x0,const result_type& s06 = 0x0,const result_type& s07 = 0x0,const result_type& s08 = 0x0,
            const result_type& s09 = 0x0,const result_type& s10 = 0x0,const result_type& s11 = 0x0,const result_type& s12 = 0x0,
            const result_type& s13 = 0x0,const result_type& s14 = 0x0,const result_type& s15 = 0x0,const result_type& s16 = 0x0)
        {
            // Inverse mask
            m_i = ~m;

            seed(s01,s02,s03,s04,
                 s05,s06,s07,s08,
                 s09,s10,s11,s12,
                 s13,s14,s15,s16);
        }

        big_wheel_engine(const big_wheel_engine<m,rs1,rs2,rs3,rs4,rm1,rm2,rf>& x)
        {
            for (std::size_t i=0;i<state_size;i++)
                state[i] = x.state[i];
            counter = x.counter;
        }

        big_wheel_engine<m,rs1,rs2,rs3,rs4,rm1,rm2,rf>& operator=(const big_wheel_engine<m,rs1,rs2,rs3,rs4,rm1,rm2,rf>& x)
        {
            for (std::size_t i=0;i<state_size;i++)
                state[i] = x.state[i];
            counter = x.counter;
            return *this;
        }

        void seed(
            const result_type& s01 = 0x0,const result_type& s02 = 0x0,const result_type& s03 = 0x0,const result_type& s04 = 0x0,
            const result_type& s05 = 0x0,const result_type& s06 = 0x0,const result_type& s07 = 0x0,const result_type& s08 = 0x0,
            const result_type& s09 = 0x0,const result_type& s10 = 0x0,const result_type& s11 = 0x0,const result_type& s12 = 0x0,
            const result_type& s13 = 0x0,const result_type& s14 = 0x0,const result_type& s15 = 0x0,const result_type& s16 = 0x0)
        {
            counter = 0;

            // Based on decimal part of sqrt(61/19)
            result_type off1[16] = {
                0xcab305ab,0x22132737,0xbda768dd,0x2438d3ab,
                0x00f4ca5a,0xd4681d61,0xc6420bc7,0x2828bdba,
                0x64806a32,0x2fa2391f,0xbc61cbca,0xcc6eb7a0,
                0xfa01a2cd,0xb766ce25,0x5499507a,0x19c839a0
            };
            // Based on decimal part of sqrt(73/29)
            result_type off2[16] = {
                0x962a374b,0x0fc75efe,0x86dfdeff,0xddb14a03,
                0xf61361c6,0xc908fde9,0x27df3b7d,0x04ae7492,
                0x5ee38142,0xfb21ee51,0x56fae74d,0x4f688f90,
                0x7889f34c,0x44e4aa33,0x547e3778,0xb6201d7b
            };
            // Based on decimal part of sqrt(79/31)
            result_type off3[16] = {
                0x98ab7f56,0x38ca9f10,0xa2f3d406,0x322c4113,
                0xb8d42dd6,0xe6490633,0x4c5bdcf7,0x454c3122,
                0x7b22e315,0x1a205e44,0xc6d1b31b,0x06eb7dea,
                0x875f1cf1,0xbe9bec2a,0x0350aa26,0x8b3d5aed
            };

            result_type sset[16] = {
                s01,s02,s03,s04,
                s05,s06,s07,s08,
                s09,s10,s11,s12,
                s13,s14,s15,s16
            };

            result_type st_a[16] = {0x0};
            result_type st_b[256] = {0x0};
            result_type st_c[4096] = {0x0};
            result_type rn_1[4096] = {0x0};
            result_type rn_2[4096] = {0x0};
            result_type rn_3[4096] = {0x0};
            result_type rn_4[4096] = {0x0};

            // Expansion
            for (std::size_t i=0;i<16;i++)
            {
                st_a[i] = sset[i]+off1[i];
                st_a[i] = smix(st_a[i],sbox_i1);
            }

            for (std::size_t i=0;i<16;i++)
            {
                for (std::size_t j=0;j<16;j++)
                {
                    st_b[16*i+j] = st_a[i]+off2[j];
                    st_b[16*i+j] = smix(st_b[16*i+j],sbox_i2);
                }
            }

            for (std::size_t i=0;i<256;i++)
            {
                for (std::size_t j=0;j<16;j++)
                {
                    st_c[16*i+j] = st_b[i]+off3[j];
                    st_c[16*i+j] = smix(st_c[16*i+j],sbox_i3);
                }
            }

            // Mixing
            for (std::size_t i=0;i<4096;i++)
            {
                rn_1[i] = (st_c[(i+ 0)%4096] << 13) | (st_c[(i+ 4)%4096] >> 19);
                rn_1[i] = smix(rn_1[i],sbox_i4);
            }
            for (std::size_t i=0;i<4096;i++)
            {
                rn_2[i] = (rn_1[(i+10)%4096] << 11) | (rn_1[(i+18)%4096] >> 21);
                rn_2[i] = smix(rn_2[i],sbox_i4);
            }
            for (std::size_t i=0;i<4096;i++)
            {
                rn_3[i] = (rn_2[(i+28)%4096] << 17) | (rn_2[(i+40)%4096] >> 15);
                rn_3[i] = smix(rn_3[i],sbox_i4);
            }
            for (std::size_t i=0;i<4096;i++)
            {
                rn_4[i] = (rn_3[(i+54)%4096] << 10) | (rn_3[(i+70)%4096] >> 22);
                rn_4[i] = smix(rn_4[i],sbox_i4);
            }

            for (std::size_t i=0;i<4096;i++)
            {
                state[i] = (rn_4[(i+88)%4096] << 16) | (rn_4[(i+108)%4096] >> 16);
                state[i] = smix(state[i],sbox_i5);
            }
        }

        // Get next random number
        result_type operator()()
        {
            // Temporal variables p[1..9] and tmp_xx are declared here

            // Elements from state to mix
            const std::size_t p1 = (counter+  0)%4096;
            const std::size_t p2 = (counter+  8)%4096;
            const std::size_t p3 = (counter+ 18)%4096;
            const std::size_t p4 = (counter+ 30)%4096;
            const std::size_t p5 = (counter+ 44)%4096;
            const std::size_t p6 = (counter+ 60)%4096;
            const std::size_t p7 = (counter+ 78)%4096;
            const std::size_t p8 = (counter+ 98)%4096;
            const std::size_t p9 = (counter+120)%4096;

            // Start mixing
            const result_type tmp_11 = (state[p1] << rs1) | (state[p2] >> (32-rs1));
            const result_type tmp_12 = (state[p3] << rs2) | (state[p4] >> (32-rs2));
            const result_type tmp_13 = (state[p5] << rs3) | (state[p6] >> (32-rs3));
            const result_type tmp_14 = (state[p7] << rs4) | (state[p8] >> (32-rs4));

            const result_type tmp_21 = ((tmp_11 << rm1) | (tmp_12 >> (32-rm1)));
            const result_type tmp_22 = ((tmp_13 << rm2) | (tmp_14 >> (32-rm2)));

            const result_type tmp_3 = (tmp_21 & m) | (tmp_22 & m_i);

            const result_type tmp_4 = rot_r(state[p9] ^ tmp_3,rf);

            state[p9] = smix(tmp_4,sbox_r);

            // For jumping to next elements
            counter++;

            return state[p9];
        }

        // Discard z elements
        void discard(unsigned long long z)
        {
            for (unsigned long long i=0;i<z;i++)
                (*this)();
        }

        // Minimum and maximum
        static constexpr result_type min()
        {
            return std::numeric_limits<result_type>::min();
        }

        static constexpr result_type max()
        {
            return std::numeric_limits<result_type>::max();
        }

        // Comparision
        friend bool operator==(
            const big_wheel_engine<m,rs1,rs2,rs3,rs4,rm1,rm2,rf>& lhs,
            const big_wheel_engine<m,rs1,rs2,rs3,rs4,rm1,rm2,rf>& rhs)
        {
            if (lhs.counter != rhs.counter)
                return false;

            for (std::size_t i=0;i<state_size;i++)
            {
                if (lhs.state[i] != rhs.state[i])
                    return false;
                else
                    continue;
            }

            return true;
        }

        friend bool operator!=(
            const big_wheel_engine<m,rs1,rs2,rs3,rs4,rm1,rm2,rf>& lhs,
            const big_wheel_engine<m,rs1,rs2,rs3,rs4,rm1,rm2,rf>& rhs)
        {
            return !(lhs == rhs);
        }

        // Stream ops
        template <class CharT,class Traits>
        friend std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& operator<<(
            std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& os,
            const big_wheel_engine<m,rs1,rs2,rs3,rs4,rm1,rm2,rf>& bw)
        {
            os << bw.counter;
            for (std::size_t i=0;i<bw.state_size;i++)
                os << ' ' << bw.state[i];

            return os;
        }

        template <class CharT,class Traits>
        friend std::basic_istream<CharT,Traits>& operator>>(
            std::basic_istream<CharT,Traits>& is,
            const big_wheel_engine<m,rs1,rs2,rs3,rs4,rm1,rm2,rf>& bw)
        {
            is >> bw.counter >> std::ws;
            for (std::size_t i=0;i<bw.state_size;i++)
                is >> bw.state[i] >> std::ws;

            return is;
        }
    private:
        // State
        result_type state[4096];

        // Reverse mask
        result_type m_i;

        // Counter (for picking elements from state)
        std::size_t counter;

        // S-boxes:
        // - sbox_i{1,2,3,4,5}: For initialization
        // -- i{1,2,3}: Seed expansion
        // -- i{4,5}:   Mixing
        // - sbox_r: For generating the next random number
        static std::uint32_t sbox_i1[256];
        static std::uint32_t sbox_i2[256];
        static std::uint32_t sbox_i3[256];
        static std::uint32_t sbox_i4[256];
        static std::uint32_t sbox_i5[256];
        static std::uint32_t sbox_r[256];

        // Left/right bit rotation
        template <typename D> D rot_l(D x,unsigned r) { return ((x << r) | (x >> (CHAR_BIT*sizeof(D)-r))); }
        template <typename D> D rot_r(D x,unsigned r) { return ((x >> r) | (x << (CHAR_BIT*sizeof(D)-r))); }

        // Mix x with an S-box sb
        result_type smix(result_type x,std::uint32_t *sb)
        {
            return result_type(
                (sb[(x >> 24)&0xff] << 24)|
                (sb[(x >> 16)&0xff] << 16)|
                (sb[(x >>  8)&0xff] <<  8)|
                (sb[(x >>  0)&0xff] <<  0)
            );
        }
};

// The S-boxes (randomly generated)
template <
    std::uint32_t m,
    std::size_t rs1,std::size_t rs2,std::size_t rs3,std::size_t rs4,
    std::size_t rm1,std::size_t rm2,
    std::size_t rf
>
std::uint32_t big_wheel_engine<m,rs1,rs2,rs3,rs4,rm1,rm2,rf>::sbox_i1[256] = {
    0x36,0x09,0x2d,0x7f,0x28,0x8a,0x51,0x81,0x2b,0x69,0x90,0x58,0xaf,0x21,0xda,0x71,
    0x8d,0x4f,0xb9,0xa4,0x91,0xbc,0xde,0x3f,0xad,0x6e,0xbd,0x5a,0xbb,0x92,0x1a,0x5d,
    0x49,0x6a,0x94,0x0a,0xaa,0x30,0xf3,0x73,0x37,0xfa,0xcf,0x7e,0x76,0xdf,0xb1,0x56,
    0xd5,0x78,0x12,0x08,0xe3,0xf1,0x07,0x9d,0x98,0xc5,0xe6,0xcd,0x34,0xf8,0xfd,0xd0,
    0x2f,0x84,0x66,0x4b,0x3c,0x4e,0xc6,0x63,0x99,0x57,0x60,0x54,0x97,0x9f,0x39,0xf0,
    0x59,0xa1,0xcb,0x18,0xed,0x0b,0xd1,0xdb,0x44,0x1e,0x0f,0x72,0x2c,0x5b,0x27,0xc9,
    0x55,0x1c,0x41,0xfc,0x11,0x50,0x4d,0x9b,0x88,0xea,0xd6,0xc8,0x45,0xa2,0xcc,0x8c,
    0xa6,0x61,0xb5,0x01,0xb4,0x6d,0x93,0xc3,0xab,0xdd,0x9e,0x6c,0x38,0xe7,0x47,0xe9,
    0x70,0x31,0xe8,0x03,0x52,0x75,0xe0,0xb6,0x53,0x40,0x46,0x0e,0x3a,0x5e,0x79,0x5c,
    0xc2,0x7c,0x7a,0x6f,0xe1,0xd4,0xb8,0x85,0xee,0x22,0xb0,0x80,0x42,0xf6,0xec,0x24,
    0xe2,0x9a,0x14,0x8f,0xac,0x15,0x10,0x82,0xa3,0x20,0x3b,0xf2,0x68,0x4c,0xd3,0x9c,
    0xca,0x48,0xfe,0x00,0x04,0xc0,0x0c,0xba,0xb7,0xc7,0x3e,0xff,0xd8,0xfb,0x6b,0x65,
    0x26,0x17,0x8b,0xf9,0x02,0xb2,0xe4,0xbf,0x8e,0xc1,0x62,0xd7,0x1d,0x77,0x2e,0x96,
    0x25,0x33,0x5f,0xef,0x35,0x43,0xf5,0xf7,0xa0,0x64,0x05,0xc4,0x1b,0xd2,0x0d,0x16,
    0xdc,0x86,0x7d,0xeb,0x87,0xa5,0x83,0xf4,0x23,0xd9,0x4a,0x95,0x1f,0x7b,0x74,0xa9,
    0x2a,0x13,0x06,0x29,0xae,0xce,0x89,0xa7,0x3d,0x19,0x67,0xa8,0x32,0xb3,0xbe,0xe5
};

template <
    std::uint32_t m,
    std::size_t rs1,std::size_t rs2,std::size_t rs3,std::size_t rs4,
    std::size_t rm1,std::size_t rm2,
    std::size_t rf
>
std::uint32_t big_wheel_engine<m,rs1,rs2,rs3,rs4,rm1,rm2,rf>::sbox_i2[256] = {
    0x2d,0xa9,0x38,0x42,0x24,0xd1,0x55,0x8a,0x3c,0x22,0x84,0x7a,0xd6,0xbc,0x2a,0xb7,
    0x99,0xd7,0xe6,0x2f,0x9e,0x1f,0x1e,0x0a,0xd0,0x97,0x45,0xe9,0x90,0x8f,0xe7,0x35,
    0x40,0x6e,0x9a,0xeb,0x28,0x75,0x03,0x5a,0x29,0x34,0x6b,0x17,0xaa,0x4a,0x6d,0x00,
    0x36,0xd8,0x71,0x9b,0xf1,0x25,0x5b,0x46,0x12,0x69,0x9d,0xb9,0x66,0xf7,0x74,0x95,
    0x61,0x48,0x1a,0x23,0xcb,0x5c,0xcd,0x70,0x18,0xb3,0x76,0x0e,0x37,0xc8,0x3a,0x92,
    0x59,0xdd,0x26,0xaf,0xb0,0x8e,0x44,0xce,0xe3,0xcf,0x4f,0x0d,0x4c,0x19,0x49,0xca,
    0x07,0xc7,0xd2,0x72,0x7b,0x3e,0xc5,0xc1,0xc2,0x91,0x86,0x4b,0x57,0xe0,0x02,0xb6,
    0xf4,0x7e,0x39,0xd9,0x20,0x65,0xac,0x87,0xb8,0x33,0xe5,0xb2,0xa1,0x96,0x64,0xa6,
    0x2b,0x01,0x85,0x50,0xed,0x27,0xff,0x62,0x30,0x80,0xc9,0xa4,0x31,0xde,0x21,0x7c,
    0xdc,0xf6,0xae,0x52,0x8c,0x51,0x32,0xbf,0x0c,0xa8,0xb4,0xe2,0xe8,0x94,0x14,0x43,
    0xd3,0xdf,0x58,0x77,0x15,0x0b,0xad,0xab,0x7f,0xbd,0xbb,0xf5,0xf9,0x1c,0x5d,0x04,
    0xdb,0x54,0xa3,0x47,0x2e,0xfd,0x67,0x53,0x60,0xee,0x6a,0xa2,0xd4,0xfe,0x8b,0x82,
    0x4e,0xc6,0xc4,0x98,0xb5,0xbe,0x06,0x3d,0x13,0xf8,0xe1,0x3b,0x81,0xa7,0x79,0x8d,
    0xf2,0xb1,0xd5,0x2c,0xc3,0x1d,0x1b,0x73,0x9f,0x6f,0xba,0xcc,0xfc,0xea,0x09,0xa0,
    0xec,0x10,0xc0,0x4d,0x11,0x0f,0x88,0x08,0x5f,0x56,0xf0,0x5e,0x63,0xfa,0x05,0x78,
    0x3f,0x7d,0x41,0xfb,0x68,0xa5,0x89,0xf3,0xef,0x83,0x6c,0x16,0xe4,0xda,0x9c,0x93
};

template <
    std::uint32_t m,
    std::size_t rs1,std::size_t rs2,std::size_t rs3,std::size_t rs4,
    std::size_t rm1,std::size_t rm2,
    std::size_t rf
>
std::uint32_t big_wheel_engine<m,rs1,rs2,rs3,rs4,rm1,rm2,rf>::sbox_i3[256] = {
    0x06,0x38,0x28,0x6a,0x51,0xb1,0x0a,0x55,0xf9,0xa3,0x73,0x11,0xed,0x3a,0x43,0x83,
    0x54,0x74,0x89,0xe0,0x85,0x10,0xcc,0x6f,0x64,0x2b,0x71,0xc1,0xa4,0x5b,0x42,0x92,
    0xc8,0x99,0x4a,0x8f,0xda,0xbc,0xb7,0x5c,0x81,0x16,0x52,0x50,0x82,0x61,0x3f,0xf5,
    0x1b,0x12,0x90,0x98,0x02,0x05,0x8d,0xa6,0x5a,0xbf,0xe9,0xa7,0x24,0x56,0xfd,0x40,
    0x33,0xe6,0x17,0x72,0xf8,0x18,0xd1,0xac,0xa2,0xfe,0x0f,0x88,0x39,0x09,0x6c,0x0e,
    0x67,0x7c,0x84,0xeb,0x8a,0xba,0x63,0x03,0x75,0xcd,0x93,0x97,0xab,0x6d,0x76,0xdc,
    0xad,0x53,0xb9,0x8e,0xd2,0x4b,0xf2,0xa5,0x4f,0x77,0x7b,0xd7,0x91,0x9f,0x20,0x70,
    0xcb,0xc3,0xb4,0x9c,0xa9,0xd8,0x9d,0xb5,0xca,0x7a,0x1a,0xc4,0x0d,0x19,0xc6,0x30,
    0xf0,0x5d,0x65,0x79,0x7e,0x2c,0x31,0x13,0x9e,0xbd,0x44,0xbe,0x57,0xb2,0xc5,0x80,
    0xe3,0x27,0xd0,0xec,0x48,0x4e,0xae,0x86,0x8c,0xf4,0x3b,0xfb,0xb3,0xa8,0x69,0xb8,
    0x1f,0x0b,0xcf,0x4c,0x45,0xaa,0xdf,0xf7,0xe8,0x68,0xef,0x58,0x34,0x7d,0xbb,0xf6,
    0x2e,0x22,0xdb,0x35,0xd6,0x6b,0x1d,0x5e,0xc0,0xa1,0x3d,0xfa,0xb0,0xff,0x60,0x2a,
    0x41,0x5f,0xc7,0xd5,0x4d,0x1e,0x2f,0x01,0xea,0x49,0xdd,0x26,0xb6,0x78,0xde,0x25,
    0x36,0xf1,0x0c,0xe1,0x04,0x32,0x14,0x3e,0x87,0x6e,0x96,0xe5,0xce,0x95,0xe2,0xaf,
    0xf3,0xa0,0x46,0x37,0x15,0x1c,0x00,0x2d,0x7f,0xe4,0x62,0xee,0x3c,0x08,0x47,0x9b,
    0x66,0xfc,0x21,0xd3,0x94,0x59,0x8b,0x07,0xd4,0x29,0xc9,0x23,0xc2,0x9a,0xe7,0xd9
};

template <
    std::uint32_t m,
    std::size_t rs1,std::size_t rs2,std::size_t rs3,std::size_t rs4,
    std::size_t rm1,std::size_t rm2,
    std::size_t rf
>
std::uint32_t big_wheel_engine<m,rs1,rs2,rs3,rs4,rm1,rm2,rf>::sbox_i4[256] = {
    0x1a,0x6b,0xfd,0xd0,0x0d,0x11,0x50,0x9e,0x1f,0xd3,0x95,0xca,0xbc,0x0c,0x80,0x29,
    0x47,0xa4,0x3f,0x3c,0x2c,0x76,0x3a,0x91,0x60,0x8d,0x39,0x9b,0x7e,0x6d,0x1b,0x12,
    0x7f,0xf3,0xab,0xb6,0x63,0x7b,0x53,0x31,0xd6,0x4d,0xbb,0xcb,0x56,0xda,0x15,0xbe,
    0x67,0xfb,0xa9,0xdb,0x69,0x97,0x42,0xf1,0x5c,0xc5,0xb3,0x34,0xa3,0x6f,0x51,0x4f,
    0xc2,0x70,0xf8,0x52,0x92,0x81,0xd1,0x0f,0xba,0x3d,0x4c,0xb0,0x48,0xff,0xd2,0x7d,
    0xaf,0x1c,0x65,0xe8,0x4b,0x5f,0x94,0xcc,0x84,0x09,0x64,0x2e,0xb1,0x77,0x96,0xea,
    0x79,0x24,0xb8,0x0e,0x90,0x33,0xf9,0xb2,0x57,0x28,0xe9,0x04,0x03,0xa1,0x17,0xe7,
    0x82,0xaa,0x19,0x83,0x43,0x9a,0xfe,0xfc,0xc6,0xef,0x1e,0xa6,0x5b,0xbd,0xdd,0x08,
    0xb9,0x16,0x9d,0xf2,0x20,0x78,0x06,0xae,0xf0,0xc3,0x59,0x45,0xb7,0xcd,0xa8,0x05,
    0xeb,0x26,0x02,0xf6,0x6e,0x8a,0x14,0x98,0x0b,0x25,0xdc,0x7c,0xc1,0x6a,0x86,0x71,
    0xed,0x68,0xec,0x85,0x35,0x87,0x18,0x93,0x46,0x23,0xd8,0x6c,0xbf,0x61,0x4a,0xac,
    0xcf,0xe3,0x1d,0xb5,0x5e,0xa0,0x9c,0xf7,0x55,0x73,0x2a,0xad,0x00,0xc8,0x75,0xf5,
    0xb4,0x8f,0xc7,0x36,0xe5,0x41,0xde,0xee,0xa7,0x9f,0xce,0xd5,0x21,0x8e,0xa5,0x32,
    0x2b,0x54,0x99,0x7a,0xe0,0x58,0xfa,0x30,0x5d,0x44,0x8b,0x8c,0x4e,0x72,0x66,0xc4,
    0x40,0x2f,0xe6,0x5a,0x2d,0x37,0x01,0x27,0xa2,0xe1,0x22,0x10,0xd7,0x3e,0x89,0x74,
    0xc0,0x38,0x88,0xd9,0x62,0x49,0xdf,0x3b,0xd4,0x0a,0x13,0xf4,0xe4,0x07,0xe2,0xc9
};

template <
    std::uint32_t m,
    std::size_t rs1,std::size_t rs2,std::size_t rs3,std::size_t rs4,
    std::size_t rm1,std::size_t rm2,
    std::size_t rf
>
std::uint32_t big_wheel_engine<m,rs1,rs2,rs3,rs4,rm1,rm2,rf>::sbox_i5[256] = {
    0x28,0x21,0xde,0xd7,0x8f,0x86,0xba,0xb3,0xeb,0xe2,0x7c,0x75,0x2d,0x24,0x18,0x11,
    0x49,0x40,0x46,0x4f,0x17,0x1e,0x22,0x2b,0x73,0x7a,0xe4,0xed,0xb5,0xbc,0x80,0x89,
    0xd1,0xd8,0x4b,0x42,0x1a,0x13,0x2f,0x26,0x7e,0x77,0xe9,0xe0,0xb8,0xb1,0x8d,0x84,
    0xdc,0xd5,0xd3,0xda,0x82,0x8b,0xb7,0xbe,0xe6,0xef,0x71,0x78,0x20,0x29,0x15,0x1c,
    0x44,0x4d,0x98,0x91,0xc9,0xc0,0xfc,0xf5,0xad,0xa4,0x3a,0x33,0x6b,0x62,0x5e,0x57,
    0x0f,0x06,0x00,0x09,0x51,0x58,0x64,0x6d,0x35,0x3c,0xa2,0xab,0xf3,0xfa,0xc6,0xcf,
    0x97,0x9e,0x0d,0x04,0x5c,0x55,0x69,0x60,0x38,0x31,0xaf,0xa6,0xfe,0xf7,0xcb,0xc2,
    0x9a,0x93,0x95,0x9c,0xc4,0xcd,0xf1,0xf8,0xa0,0xa9,0x37,0x3e,0x66,0x6f,0x53,0x5a,
    0x02,0x0b,0xf4,0xfd,0xa5,0xac,0x90,0x99,0xc1,0xc8,0x56,0x5f,0x07,0x0e,0x32,0x3b,
    0x63,0x6a,0x6c,0x65,0x3d,0x34,0x08,0x01,0x59,0x50,0xce,0xc7,0x9f,0x96,0xaa,0xa3,
    0xfb,0xf2,0x61,0x68,0x30,0x39,0x05,0x0c,0x54,0x5d,0xc3,0xca,0x92,0x9b,0xa7,0xae,
    0xf6,0xff,0xf9,0xf0,0xa8,0xa1,0x9d,0x94,0xcc,0xc5,0x5b,0x52,0x0a,0x03,0x3f,0x36,
    0x6e,0x67,0xb2,0xbb,0xe3,0xea,0xd6,0xdf,0x87,0x8e,0x10,0x19,0x41,0x48,0x74,0x7d,
    0x25,0x2c,0x2a,0x23,0x7b,0x72,0x4e,0x47,0x1f,0x16,0x88,0x81,0xd9,0xd0,0xec,0xe5,
    0xbd,0xb4,0x27,0x2e,0x76,0x7f,0x43,0x4a,0x12,0x1b,0x85,0x8c,0xd4,0xdd,0xe1,0xe8,
    0xb0,0xb9,0xbf,0xb6,0xee,0xe7,0xdb,0xd2,0x8a,0x83,0x1d,0x14,0x4c,0x45,0x79,0x70
};

template <
    std::uint32_t m,
    std::size_t rs1,std::size_t rs2,std::size_t rs3,std::size_t rs4,
    std::size_t rm1,std::size_t rm2,
    std::size_t rf
>
std::uint32_t big_wheel_engine<m,rs1,rs2,rs3,rs4,rm1,rm2,rf>::sbox_r[256] = {
    0xe9,0xe0,0xdc,0xd5,0x8d,0x84,0x1a,0x13,0x4b,0x42,0x7e,0x77,0x2f,0x26,0x20,0x29,
    0x71,0x78,0x44,0x4d,0x15,0x1c,0x82,0x8b,0xd3,0xda,0xe6,0xef,0xb7,0xbe,0x6b,0x62,
    0x3a,0x33,0x0f,0x06,0x5e,0x57,0xc9,0xc0,0x98,0x91,0xad,0xa4,0xfc,0xf5,0xf3,0xfa,
    0xa2,0xab,0x97,0x9e,0xc6,0xcf,0x51,0x58,0x00,0x09,0x35,0x3c,0x64,0x6d,0xfe,0xf7,
    0xaf,0xa6,0x9a,0x93,0xcb,0xc2,0x5c,0x55,0x0d,0x04,0x38,0x31,0x69,0x60,0x66,0x6f,
    0x37,0x3e,0x02,0x0b,0x53,0x5a,0xc4,0xcd,0x95,0x9c,0xa0,0xa9,0xf1,0xf8,0x07,0x0e,
    0x56,0x5f,0x63,0x6a,0x32,0x3b,0xa5,0xac,0xf4,0xfd,0xc1,0xc8,0x90,0x99,0x9f,0x96,
    0xce,0xc7,0xfb,0xf2,0xaa,0xa3,0x3d,0x34,0x6c,0x65,0x59,0x50,0x08,0x01,0x92,0x9b,
    0xc3,0xca,0xf6,0xff,0xa7,0xae,0x30,0x39,0x61,0x68,0x54,0x5d,0x05,0x0c,0x0a,0x03,
    0x5b,0x52,0x6e,0x67,0x3f,0x36,0xa8,0xa1,0xf9,0xf0,0xcc,0xc5,0x9d,0x94,0x41,0x48,
    0x10,0x19,0x25,0x2c,0x74,0x7d,0xe3,0xea,0xb2,0xbb,0x87,0x8e,0xd6,0xdf,0xd9,0xd0,
    0x88,0x81,0xbd,0xb4,0xec,0xe5,0x7b,0x72,0x2a,0x23,0x1f,0x16,0x4e,0x47,0xd4,0xdd,
    0x85,0x8c,0xb0,0xb9,0xe1,0xe8,0x76,0x7f,0x27,0x2e,0x12,0x1b,0x43,0x4a,0x4c,0x45,
    0x1d,0x14,0x28,0x21,0x79,0x70,0xee,0xe7,0xbf,0xb6,0x8a,0x83,0xdb,0xd2,0x2d,0x24,
    0x7c,0x75,0x49,0x40,0x18,0x11,0x8f,0x86,0xde,0xd7,0xeb,0xe2,0xba,0xb3,0xb5,0xbc,
    0xe4,0xed,0xd1,0xd8,0x80,0x89,0x17,0x1e,0x46,0x4f,0x73,0x7a,0x22,0x2b,0xb8,0xb1
};

#endif
```

Any improvements and suggestions, especially about the use of multithreading and asynchronous calling, are welcome.